# Data not passing from controller to model Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am having troubles passing data from the controller to the model in opencart(1.5.3). I have modified the 'add products' form to include a file input field, however, the results I am experiencing, I don't understand, so I'd appreciate any input, or suggestions as to a solution.

When I post the form, the data is sent to the controller, but the controller does not pass it to the model, which stops the final database query from being executed.

Im not sure if this is part of this issue, but in firebug, the post data is defined in the source list, but the field name is not defined in the parts list.

Below is an example of the code. It might be worth mentioning that I am using VQmod to add changes on the fly.

View:

```
      <table class="form">
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $entry_product_pins; ?></td>
          <td><input type="file" name="product_pins" /><?php echo $tab_pins_instructions; ?>
      </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

Controller:

```
    if (isset($this->request->files['product_pins']['tmp_name'])) {

    $this->data['product_pins'] = file_get_contents($this->request->files['product_pins']['tmp_name']); 

                    } else {

    $this->data['product_pins'] = '';

   }
```

Model:

```
            if ( isset($this->data['product_pins']) ) {

                foreach (explode(";\n", $this->data['product_pins']) as $pin) {

                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_pins SET pin_product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', pin_pin_number = '" . $this->db->escape($pin) . "'");
              }

            } else { 

// added for debugging

exit("product_pins not set"); }
```

Comment: It's unclear here as to what you are doing, and if you're trying to get data to the view or the model exactly? When data is passed to the model from the product form, it's the $this->request->post that gets passed to the model. $this->request->files does not

Comment: @JayGilford ok, I need to import a cvs file of pins into the database(its own table), and associate it with a product id. I created the mod in the insert product form so that this association could be easily achieved(upon editing/adding product). In my thinking, the form data goes into the $this->data array through the controller, gets validated, which then passes it to the model..is this not right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Form Submission -> post data validation -> passed to model` is the path in theory. What you need to do is take the pins from the `$this->request->files` and put it into the post data when you validate (at least that's the way I would do it), or pass the filename to the model method and extract it in the model, though that tends to get a little trickier then